# Сборка приложения на Pyqt5 pyinstaller с изображениями

Tags: python, pyqt5, pyinstaller

Как правильно собрать приложение на macOs чтобы при запуске подгружались картинки? Сейчас установлены такие зависимости [image: зависимости], но после установки приложение долго запускается и не отображаются картинки для объектов.
Картинки для объектов я подгружаю так [image: следующим образом]
и выполняю такую команду pyinstaller --onefile --noconsole main.py
После сборки, рядом с приложением, папку с картинками вложил

Comment: Каталог `images/icon` находится рядом с `main.exe` ?  `main.exe` - запускаете из каталога где лежит сам `main.exe` или как ?

Comment: Совершенно верно. Каталог с графическими файлами находится в одной директории с main.exe и запускаю этот же exe